# Can't load resource file in Shared project

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two project - shared project and wpf project.
And there is a html file in shared project.
I want to get stream of the file using below code.

```
var resourceName = String.Format("{0}.Map.html", this.GetType().Namespace);
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
```

But It returns null always.
I checked resource names with below code.

```
var names = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

I can't see the html file from the list.
I added the file with Add Existing Item Dialog.
I'm not sure. What is wrong.
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. select the resource file and in the property window change build action with embedded resource.
It's working perfectly.